# CSS scan media query

Tags: css, media-queries

is the `scan` media feature only allowed to be used with the `tv` media type? If not which media types can I also use with it? And can I use the `scan` media feature by itself?

Comment: Your question needs a more descriptive title. Actually specify what your question in the title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "yes" progressive scan television screens.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#scan

Comment: so I can only use the tv media type?

Comment: Yeah. It will allow you to load a stylesheet crafted for either progressive scan or interlaced devices.